# spaces in Inline-block, block elements in divs and images

Tags: html, css

Working on a youtube designed web
but I faced a problem. I created a `<div>` and gave an image to it, but whenever I set the display to inline-block, there is a little space between the border of the div and image. But if I set the display to block, the space between them is gone.
Why is this happening?
Images:
[display: inline-block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53YUN.png)
[display: block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHrXJ.png)

```css
.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /*  <<<<<<<<<  */
}

.search-bar {
  display: block;
}

.video-title {
  width: 300px;
}

.video-preview {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.test {
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<input class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search">
<div class="video-preview">
  <div class="test">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="PICs/hq720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="PICs/Channel Prof/fireship.jpg">
    <p class="video-title">Why so many distros? The Weird History of Linux</p>
    <p class="video-author">Fireship</p>
    <p class="video-stats">1.4M views &#183; 2 years ago</p>
  </div>
```